# Is the ShellPresenter in Prism a (P)resenter as in the MVP pattern?

Tags: prism

I'm tring to grok Prism (Composite Application Guidelines).

What is the best way to understand the role of the ShellPresenter? Is it a presenter as in Model-View-Presenter?

Is so, what is its relationship to the Shell? I understand that the ShellPresenter takes the Shell object as a parameter of its constructor and is responsible for making sure all the Modules place their views in the proper regions. But then there is also the RegionManager which does this.

Any clarification from those who have been working with this terminology for while would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ShellPresenter is a Presenter in the MVP pattern.

The regionManager really acts as a registry of known Regions - its technically an Adaptor to the said Presenter.

So whilst on the surface the ShellPresenter could technically handle its own Children management, by using the [Adaptor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) one can de-couple this logic and promote re-usuage throughout since it's likely to be constantly used? (ie think multiple inheritance work-around).

Does that help?

**Scott Barnes - Rich Platforms Product Manager - Microsoft.**